# Building a desk-Does it need reinforcement?

Tags: metal, construction, hardwood, desk, table

I'm build a computer desk, but I've been agonizing over the build because I'm concerned that there might not be enough support.  These are the details:

Table top: Teak butcher block with a live edge 74in wide by 25in deep by 1.5in thick and weighs 76 lbs.
Supports: 2x Metal leg frames (H frame or some variation) each leg supports about 400 lbs.  They are 28in high by 24in wide, although I'm considering one that is 34in high by 24in wide.

Usage: I'll be mounting a 32 pound monitor to a desk arm using a grommet hole mounting style.  I'll also be attaching a sliding keyboard\mouse tray.  I'll also be mounting 2 tower computers underneath the desk, each one will be near one of the table legs.  It will also hold a couple of laptops, a couple of controllers, and maybe my arms and head during frustrating moments in time (totally serious).

Environment:  High humidity(60-80%) moderate temperature(40-70) basement.  This is the reason I chose teak.

The Concern:  I thinking about the weight in the middle of this table.  Would this 6ft span require some kind of ribbing to prevent it from bowing\warping\snapping in the center?  Or am I over engineering?

I do not see a lot of stress being put on the center portion of the desk.  But, I like to build for the future, so if something changes where the function of the desk changes, I want to be prepared.

So does anyone think this table needs reinforcement?

Comment: Welcome to DiY! Do you have a sketch of some sort of your intended setup? With lots of text it's easy to misread what you may have in mind.

Comment: Maybe if it was 1/2 or 3/4 inch thick.  One and a half should hold a lot more weight than you are planning.  1 and 1/2 should hold you sitting on it, jumping up and down probably not fun times.

Comment: 1.5" should make it plenty strong. But if your legs are inset a bit - perhaps 10" each and put the computers to the outer sides of the legs instead of the middle - then your center span will be much shorter and, therefore, more stable.

Comment: Might I suggest a visit to [The Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/). I'd agree that a 1.5" thick slab is likely to be _plenty_ sturdy. However, it _will_ be subject to racking forces - what if someone leans on one end of the desk. It'll want to push sideways (in the 74" direction) and collapse that way.

Comment: Agree with @FreeMan about racking. A short panel at the top/ back that holds the leg structures in place will help. You might have to add more bracing as needed, but start there.

Comment: You might also skew the legs out wider at the front.

Comment: "Usage: I'll be mounting a 32 pound monitor to a desk arm using a grommet hole mounting style." *oh there it is.  Right on cue.   This is where all desk projects fail.  The force on those holes is *extreme*.